# What techniques used in this triangulation low poly tutorial

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[This low poly tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2KaAKDMsHw) made using illustrator shows how the artist rapidly uses eyedropper and pen tool to draw and fill triangles.

You can see that he ain't adjusting the triangles and still can make perfectly adjacent triangles, what do you think is he doing?, including keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

He's merely drawing triangles with the **Pen Tool**. Smart Guides are active to allow the paths to "snap" to each other and there *is* an occasional adjustment to the triangles as seen when the Bounding Box appears for a brief moment.

Comment: lol, before the edit was a mean answer., gotta check the smart guides which is probably the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Not a mean answer, at least it wasn't meant to be one. There honestly isn't always a magic button.

Comment: I understand what you feel, but not even a second I thought of doing this by the "magic button", I've realized that upon creating this in ps alone http://iamspix.deviantart.com/art/The-Unfinished-Final-169560980